# JSON Templating in Node/Express

Tags: json, node.js, express, templating

Does Node/Express have a JSON templating engine like RABL (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or JBuilder? (http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast). I don't mean an HTML templating engine like Handlebars, Jade, or Underscore.js. I mean a JSON templating engine. These libraries simplify picking and choosing the elements and associations of your JSON.

Comment: Not that i'm aware of, however, since the JSON syntax is based on javascript objects, and you're writing javascript, there are plenty of tools available with javascript alone that should make transforming your data into the desired JSON format relatively easy. Even moreso if you use the harmony flags to enable es6.

Comment: Yes there are a couple... I don't remember the names of either, but they exist.  It doesn't really have anything to do with Node.js nor Express.  Check out this list here:  https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js  It's probably in there.

Comment: @Brad these are all HTML templating engines, not JSON. 

These comments sound dismissive, but RABL helps a lot (no matter what the underlying data structure is). I would like to have the equivalent without writing a bunch of underscore.js boilerplate every query.

Comment: @ajbraus Hmmm, I guess I don't get it.  I thought you meant a templating engine that uses JSON directly for the document structure.

Comment: @Brad nope. RABL lets you customize an object and outputs JSON its like between the ORM and the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's one finally! 
Here is the link to it https://www.npmjs.com/package/javelin
Also this is in the experimental stage so its not production ready yet.

Here's an extract from the link

javelin sets out with a few main goals in mind:

- An easy, familiar, way to separate the view logic from your data within RESTful APIs
- A simple, lightweight templating language that makes sense for application data
- Ability to serve your API data in different formats from the same view

Lastly, this is heavily inspired from RABL.

Hope that helps!